# Wordpress MySQL will not execute variable in query string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out why my query isn't running, and if it is; why isn't it returning any info. I'm running this query on wordpress multisite based on a plugging that goes through all network sites and retrieves all posts in the main site, that part is working fine. I created a bit of code to merge two variables into one variable to create a table name, if I echo that variable it displays the table name correctly, but when i insert the same variable in the query noting happens even dough the table already exists in the DB. the code is below:

```
 // Switch to the blog
 switch_to_blog($all_blogkeys[$field->guid]);
 global $wpdb;
 $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;  //get current site table prefix
 $table = 'rex_listings';  // name to attach to prefix
 $tablename = $prefix.''.$table;  // combine prefix and name
 //start the query and echo results
 $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT price, bedrooms, baths, floor_space, formatted_address FROM $tablename');
 foreach($result as $row) {
 echo 'Price: '.$row->price.', Bedrooms: '.$row->bedrooms.', Baths: '.$row->baths.', Floor Space: '.$row->floor_space.', Address: '.$row->formatted_address.',<br/>';}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check on this query in die('SELECT price, bedrooms, baths, floor_space, formatted_address FROM $tablename'); what it should be result

Comment: that kills the query and breaks the plugin, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes around the query and curly brackets around the variable, like so:

```
 $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT price, bedrooms, baths, floor_space, formatted_address FROM {$tablename}");
```

Comment: That works great thanks for the fast reply all I need to do now is a join between post id and listing id. thanks a lot.